# Вывести книги определенного автора по возрастанию года издания(Как рационально)

Tags: c#, консоль

Существует файл. В нем записаны данные в виде:

```
Фамилия_Автора Название_книги:Год_Книги_Число
```

Если пользователь вводит фамилию автора - Выводим его книги с 1980

1. Я нашел строки с нужным автором и записал их в `List<string> books`.
2. Теперь у меня в памяти есть `List<string>` с именем `books`, заполненный строками книг в виде `Фамилия_Автора Название_книги :Год_Книги_Число`.
   Нужно отсортировать их по возрастанию года выпуска (т.е сначала 1980-е, потом 1990-е и т.д.).

Вопрос - как отсортировать?

Еще у меня есть подозрения, что я пошел не самым рациональным методом... Поэтому проблемы.

Заношу данные из файла:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.Default))
// считываем строки файла, чтобы найти строки, содержащие заданные строки.
// Encoding.Default - (При отсутствии - знак кирилицы будет считываться как �)
// Получает кодировку для текущей кодовой страницы ANSI операционной системы.
{
    if (line.Contains(selectedAuthor))
    {
        if(Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':',0)+1)) >= fromYear)
        {
            books.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Знаю, что можно попробовать через свойство OrderBy, но как добиться сортировки по годам?

Comment: структура данных у вас какая? В общем, побольше кода

Comment: Добавил занесение в List

Comment: еще раз: КАКАЯ СТРУКТУРА ДАННЫХ?

Comment: List<string> books

Comment: хм...а почему бы не сделать отдельный класс, который будет моделировать книгу и десериализовывать его экземпляры из файла?

Comment: Вы думаете, стоит так сделать? Приблизительно представляю о чем вы

Comment: я не думаю, я знаю. Какой смысл заниматься извращениями и выдергивать данные из "сырой" строки? Ничего кроме лишних трудностей это не принесет

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить данные о книге в строковом формате не очень рационально. Продуктивнее будет создать отдельный класс для книги:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int PublicationYear
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

После чего создаете функцию для преобразования строки в объект книги:

```
public static Book ParseBook(string str)
{
    // Implementation 
}
```

Затем используете методы LINQ для преобразования всех строк из файла в книги и последующей обработке:

```
var books = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.Default).Select(ParseBook);
var booksWrittenBySelectedAuthor = books.Where(b => b.Author == selectedAuthor).OrderBy(b => b.PublicationYear).ToList();
```

Comment: Переменной Title без Book не существует

Comment: Немного запутался в public static Book ParseBook(string str)

Comment: public static Book ParseBook(string str)
        {
            Book book =new Book();
            book.Author = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(':'));
            str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(':'));
            book.Title = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(':'));
            str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(':'));
            book.PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(':')));
            return book;
        }

Comment: У вас ведь вроде автор и название книги разбиты пробелом, а не двоеточием

Comment: Я поправил, чтобы было Автор:Имя:Год  :)

Comment: Можно с Вами связаться по скайпу? Пожалуйтса!

Comment: тогда так:

    char[] separator = new char() {':'};

    var tmp = str.Split(separator);
    
    book.Author = tmp[0];

    book.Title  = tmp[1];

    book.PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[2]);

Comment: Сделал, далее вывел все строки из booksWrittenBySelectedAuthor с помощью foreach но не работает, не выводит книгу в консоль. Без исключений и ошибок

Comment: В смысле не выводит?

Comment: К сожалению, где-то я допустил лог. ошибку, только вот не пойму где, вроде все верно написано, можете посмотреть программу?  Я был бы вам очень презрителен

Comment: Не появляется окно консоли, не выводит вообще ничего в окне консоли, выводит колонку надписей Book?

Comment: не выводит вообще ничего в окне консоли

Comment: Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());

Comment: foreach (Book line in booksWrittenBySelectedAuthor)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
                }

Comment: public static Book ParseBook(string str)
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            char separator = ':'; 
            var tmp = str.Split(separator); 
            book.Author = tmp[0];
            book.Title = tmp[1];
            book.PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[2]);
            return book;
        }

Comment: Тогда  у вас должны выводится строчки Book

Comment: Ничего, к сожалению, не выводится, можно скинуть проект Вам на почту?

Comment: foreach(var n in booksWrittenBySelectedAuthor) { Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", n.Author, n.Title, n.PublicationYear) }

Comment: Пустой Вывод в консоли

Comment: var books = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.Default).Select(ParseBook);

Comment: var booksWrittenBySelectedAuthor = books.Where(b => b.Author == selectedAuthor).OrderBy(b => b.PublicationYear).ToList();

Comment: public static Book ParseBook(string str)
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            char separator = ':'; 
            var tmp = str.Split(separator); 
            book.Author = tmp[0];
            book.Title = tmp[1];
            book.PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[2]);
            return book;
        } В классе, где функция Main()

Comment: Если шагать программу -  Представление результатов Раскрытие представления результатов вызовет перечисление IEnumerable 
-  base {"Входная строка имела неверный формат."} System.SystemException {System.FormatException}

Comment: Выложите код, как отдельный вопрос, иначе мы тут сожрем все комментарии, и укажите в какой строке кидает экзепшин

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413029/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0